# Counting the rows in a TDbGrid

Tags: delphi, datagrid

I have a TDbGrid, and I can easily tell how many columns are in it at runtime with the FieldCount property, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding RowCount property to display how many records are being displayed.  How can I find this out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount
```

Maybe there are better solutions. But this worked for me.

Comment: TDataSet.RecordCount will often give -1 depending on the situation (like queries).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I have to do some db programming, else I'm losing the touch. (Two years working on a DB less app).

Comment: Indeed, Lars? So much time using TClientDataset, I didn't remember that. What kind of Query objects (ADO, IBX or DBX) show this behavior? I believe dbx would, because it's components are unidirectional cursors - but there are more?

Answer (score 14):

Both `RowCount` and `VisibleRowCount` are protected properties in `TCustomGrid` that are not exposed in `TDBGrid`. But you can get round that doing the following:

```
type
  TDummyGrid = class(TDBGrid);

  RowCount := TDummyGrid(MyDBGrid).RowCount;
  VisibleRowCount := TDummyGrid(MyDBGrid).VisibleRowCount;
```

Be warned that this includes the header.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
TDbGrid.ApproxCount
```