# How to determine Delphi DBGrid Row Count

Tags: database, delphi, properties

I have a **DBGrid** that shows a filtered view of a dBASE table.

DBGrid has a property called **RowCount** but is marked private.

How do I determine the row count?

All I really need to know, is whether the count is more than zero.

Using delphi Turbo Professional

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294342/counting-the-rows-in-a-tdbgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check DataSet.IsEmpty property

```
if not DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.IsEmpty then
  ShowMessage(Format('DBGrid ''%s'' has more than one record.', [DBGrid.Name]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the .RecordCount property of the grid's DataSource's DataSet, the DBASE table itself.

Comment: Would that give me the filtered row count or the total row count?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the filtered count. You can try it.  Also check the link on Bruce's answer above.